# How to erase all Konsole preferences?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, konsole

I was configuring my terminal preferences in Konsole and made it so it runs a command every time I open terminal. But the command is invalid so as soon as I open it, the app closes. How would I erase all my terminal preferences without access to the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your version of Kubuntu? The answer may depend on that! Things change between kde4 and kde5 and even from one version of plasma to the next.

Comment: @DKBose Hi, Im using version 18.04

Comment: How did you configure this? If you edited the file `.bashrc` in your home directory, you can open the file browser, show hidden files, open .bashrc (double clicking should open it in the default graphical text editor for your environment) and find the problem there (and also fix it)

Comment: @Zanna Hi, I edited it in the built in konsole preferences and didn't edit the bashrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: as zanna suggests, if you've done something to your `~/.bashrc` file, undo whatever you did.

---

I used the `locate` command to find konsole-related files in my home folder.

```
$ locate konsole | grep -i home | grep -v cache
/home/dkb/.config/konsole.notifyrc
/home/dkb/.config/konsolerc
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/Breeze.colorscheme
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/Linux.colorscheme
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/Profile 1.profile
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/Solarized.colorscheme
/home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/bookmarks.xml
/home/dkb/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole
/home/dkb/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/konsoleui.rc
/home/dkb/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/sessionui.rc
$
```

There are three candidates:

- /home/dkb/.config/konsolerc
- /home/dkb/.local/share/konsole/ and
- /home/dkb/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/

Ensure that `konsole` isn't running. `pgrep konsole` should come up blank. Then, using Dolphin, carefully rename `konsolerc` to something else and do the same for the two `konsole` folders.

Now, when you open `konsole`, it will recreate the contents of whatever you've renamed and that should fix things. I can't be more specific because I haven't had something similar happen to me.

Comment: Hi, I can't find the dkb folder in my home folder. I looked at all of the hidden files as well and it wasnt there

Comment: `dkb` is my username. You'll have something that matches your username, your login name.

Comment: Got it, I deleted the profile files in /home/dkb/.local/share/konsole. Thanks for the help!